# Eclipse: Apache Tomcat doesn't update my project until I restarted Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat

I have tested my a simple `form.html`. I change something on here, and right click on project, run on server.  My server (Apache Tomcat) will run my project.

But, I don't know why, it rarely update my project. (mean `form.html` no change !!!) until I restart eclipse and run project again.

Maybe the strange thing is : no message box appear asked me: "Do you want to restart server" like before. But I have config in Eclipse that "always restarted server when required" to "always". But, after I change something like some space in `form.html`, I just see that Eclipse save and run project. (not stop and start server again). Maybe the problem here !!!

(before that, I have clicked that not restart server, and remember this action), but I don't know how to config again for this

Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open the "Server" view and doubleclick on your server. Check the server location and deploy path. Open the publish tab and make sure "*automatically publish when resource changes*" is selected. Static resources will be hot deployed and there's no need to restart the server.

You can always republish resources by clicking your servers name in the Server view and then clicking the icon to the very right (in the header), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

The "restart server" function can be modified here: **window > prefereces > server > launching**.

Comment: Oh thanks :) `republish resources` works very very NICE for me :D

Comment: **It is worth noting that Eclipse does not notice file changes outside Eclipse. If you change a file outside Eclipse remember to refresh (F5) the parent directory or the whole WebContent directory!** (Sorry for having made all bold, but that drove me crazy.)

Comment: You can also try the settings in Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace (native hooks, ...), but does not help much. I hope they will integrade a [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#overview) for all files in the workspace soon.